# LINQ - Multiple Where based on conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I want to query a table with some conditions based on user input.

I have this code:

```
   IQueryable<Turno> turnoQuery = dc.Turno;

    if (helper.FechaUltimaCitaDesde != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        turnoQuery = turnoQuery.Where(t => t.TurnoFecha >= helper.FechaUltimaCitaDesde);
    }
    if (helper.FechaUltimaCitaHasta != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
       turnoQuery = turnoQuery.Where(t => t.TurnoFecha <= helper.FechaUltimaCitaHasta);
    }

    if (helper.SoloCitasConsumidas)
    {
       turnoQuery = turnoQuery.Where(t => t.Estado == Convert.ToInt32(EnmEstadoDelTurno.Consumido));
    }
    else if(helper.AnuladoresDeCitas)
    {
     turnoQuery = turnoQuery.Where(t => t.Estado == Convert.ToInt32(EnmEstadoDelTurno.Cancelado) || t.Estado == Convert.ToInt32(EnmEstadoDelTurno.Ausente));
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that the "where" clause gets overwritten with the last one.

Whats the correct way to do something like this on LINQ?

The "helper" object is a custom class storing the user input dates for this example.

Comment: Use the code button please to make your code more readable.

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stepped over with the last one"?

Comment: I already edited to make the code more readable. Was a bad paste. 
What i mean by "gets stepped.." is that the only where clause that remains on the query is the last one. Its like it only supports ONE where clause and uses always the last one it accessed. Is it clearer now?  Sry for my English :S

Comment: Based on my experience this should work. I have code that looks virtually identical to this and I don't have issues with the last where clause overriding all the previous ones. I believe you're doing it the correct way, you just have a minor bug somewhere.

Comment: MichaC, you were right. I was having some minor Bug. And it Works. I was using dcp's approach (Thanks for that dcp!) when I read your post and checked the code again and found a bug after the code I pasted. Thanks you all!

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the expressions by using a series of ternary operations. This isn't tested so there may be some syntax issues, but here's the basic idea:

```
turnoQuery = turnoQuery.Where(
  t => t.TurnoFecha >= helper.FechaUltimaCitaDesde != DateTime.MinValue ? helper.FechaUltimaCitaDesde : DateTime.MinValue &&
       t.TurnoFecha <= helper.FechaUltimaCitaHasta != DateTime.MinValue ? helper.FechaUltimaCitaHasta : DateTime.MaxValue &&
       helper.SoloCitasConsumidas ? t.Estado == Convert.ToInt32(EnmEstadoDelTurno.Consumido : 
           t.Estado == Convert.ToInt32(EnmEstadoDelTurno.Cancelado) || t.Estado == Convert.ToInt32(EnmEstadoDelTurno.Ausente) &&
       helper.FechaUltimaCitaDesde != DateTime.MinValue ? t.TurnoFecha >= helper.FechaUltimaCitaDesde : t.TurnoFecha <= helper.FechaUltimaCitaHasta &&
       helper.SoloCitasConsumidas ? t.Estado == Convert.ToInt32(EnmEstadoDelTurno.Consumido) : t.Estado == Convert.ToInt32(EnmEstadoDelTurno.Cancelado) || t.Estado == Convert.ToInt32(EnmEstadoDelTurno.Ausente)
);
```

Comment: I re-wrote this again and it also worked. Thanks for the help but I was having a minor bug and don't need this in the end.